# Prove any sequence a set has a uniformly convergent subsequence using Arzela-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, sequence-of-function

Consider the subset of $C([0, 1])$ given by
$$S = \{f \in C([0, 1]) : f(0) = 0, \int_{0}^{1} |f'(x)|^2 dx \leq 1 \}$$ 
How to prove that any sequence in this set $S$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence using Arzela-Ascoli Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem). I guess one can show that $S$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, but not sure how.

Answers very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: key tools will be the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(z)-f(y) = \int_y^z f'(x)\,dx$, and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nate Eldredge already said it all:
\begin{align*}
|f(z)-f(y)|&=\left|\int_{y}^{z}f'(x)dx\right|\\
&\leq\int_{y}^{z}|f'(x)|dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|\chi_{[y,z]}dx\\
&\leq\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|
^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}|z-y|^{1/2},
\end{align*}
for $z\geq y$, the rest should be straight forward.

Comment: I guess this proves uniform boundedness, how would I use the $\epsilon - \delta$ argument to prove equicontinuity. I am kind flustered by the square root term of $|z - y|$

Comment: Actually you can pick $\delta=\epsilon^{2}$ so if $|z-y|<\delta$, then we have immediately that $|z-y|<\epsilon$.